requested array has an inhomogeneous shape
I want to save the results of the game in the folder which is located here C:\123\train_data (i.e. data should be saved in the folder train_data).
But I can't I get this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\123\sc2.txt", line 259, in <module>
    run_game(maps.get("(2)BurialGrounds"), [
  File "C:\Users\bakshsh{AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sc2\main.py", line 325, in run_game
    result = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 654, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bakshth\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sc2\main.py", line 253, in _host_game
    result = await _play_game(players[0], client, realtime, portconfig, step_time_limit, game_time_limit, rgb_render_config)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bakshth\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sc2\main.py", line 223, in _play_game
    result = await _play_game_ai(client, player_id, player.ai, realtime, step_time_limit, game_time_limit)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bakshsh\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sc2\main.py", line 127, in _play_game_ai
    ai.on_end(client._game_result[player_id])
  File "c:\123\sc2.txt", line 29, in on_end
    np.save("train_data/{}.npy".format(str(int(int(time.time()))), np.array(self.train_data)))
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (24, 2) + inhomogeneous part.

And here's my code
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sc2
from sc2 import run_game, maps, Race, Difficulty, position, Result
from sc2.player import Bot, Computer
from sc2.constants import HATCHERY, DRONE, LARVA, OVERLORD, EXTRACTOR, SPAWNINGPOOL, ROACHWARREN, ZERGLING, ROACH
import random
import time

HEADLESS = True

class AloKostBot(sc2.BotAI):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ITERATIONS_PER_MINUTE = 165
        self.MAX_WORKERS = 88
        self.do_something_after = 0
        self.train_data = []

    def on_end(self, game_result):
        print('--- on_end called ---')
        print(game_result)

        if game_result == Result.Victory:
            np.save("train_data/{}.npy".format(str(int(time.time()))), np.array(self.train_data))



    async def on_step(self, iteration):
        self.iteration = iteration
        await self.scout()
        await self.distribute_workers()
        await self.build_workers()
        await self.build_overlords()
        await self.build_extractor()
        await self.expand()
        await self.offensive_force_buildings()
        await self.build_offensive_force()
        await self.intel()
        await self.attack()

    def random_location_variance(self, enemy_start_location):
        x = enemy_start_location[0]
        y = enemy_start_location[1]

        x += ((random.randrange(-20, 20))/100) * enemy_start_location[0]
        y += ((random.randrange(-20, 20))/100) * enemy_start_location[1]

        if x < 0:
            x = 0
        if y < 0:
            y = 0
        if x > self.game_info.map_size[0]:
            x = self.game_info.map_size[0]
        if y > self.game_info.map_size[1]:
            y = self.game_info.map_size[1]

        go_to = position.Point2(position.Pointlike((x,y)))
        return go_to
    
    async def scout(self):
        if len(self.units(ZERGLING)) > 0:
            scout = self.units(ZERGLING)[0]
            if scout.is_idle:
                enemy_location = self.enemy_start_locations[0]
                move_to = self.random_location_variance(enemy_location)
                print(move_to)
                await self.do(scout.move(move_to))

        else:
            for l in self.units(LARVA).ready.noqueue:
                if self.can_afford(ZERGLING):
                    await self.do(l.train(ZERGLING))

    async def intel(self):
        game_data = np.zeros((self.game_info.map_size[1], self.game_info.map_size[0], 3), np.uint8)

        draw_dict = {
                    HATCHERY: [15, (0, 255, 0)],
                    DRONE: [1, (55, 200, 0)],
                    EXTRACTOR: [2, (55, 200, 0)],
                    SPAWNINGPOOL: [3, (200, 100, 0)],
                    ROACHWARREN: [3, (150, 150, 0)],

                    ROACH: [3, (20, 235, 0)],
                    #ZERGLING: [3, (255, 255, 255)],
                    }
        
        for unit_type in draw_dict:
            for unit in self.units(unit_type).ready:
                pos = unit.position
                cv2.circle(game_data, (int(pos[0]), int(pos[1])), draw_dict[unit_type][0], draw_dict[unit_type][1], -1)

        main_base_names = ["nexus", "supplydepot", "hatchery"]
        for enemy_building in self.known_enemy_structures:
            pos = enemy_building.position
            if enemy_building.name.lower() not in main_base_names:
                cv2.circle(game_data, (int(pos[0]), int(pos[1])), 5, (200, 50, 212), -1)
        for enemy_building in self.known_enemy_structures:
            pos = enemy_building.position
            if enemy_building.name.lower() in main_base_names:
                cv2.circle(game_data, (int(pos[0]), int(pos[1])), 15, (0, 0, 255), -1)

        for enemy_unit in self.known_enemy_units:
            if not enemy_unit.is_structure:
                worker_names = ["probe",
                                "scv",
                                "drone"]
                pos = enemy_unit.position
                if enemy_unit.name.lower() in worker_names:
                    cv2.circle(game_data, (int(pos[0]), int(pos[1])), 1, (55, 0, 155), -1)
                else:
                    cv2.circle(game_data, (int(pos[0]), int(pos[1])), 3, (50, 0, 215), -1)

        for z in self.units(ZERGLING).ready:
            pos = z.position
            cv2.circle(game_data, (int(pos[0]), int(pos[1])), 1, (255, 255, 255), -1)

        line_max = 50
        mineral_ratio = self.minerals / 1500
        if mineral_ratio > 1.0:
            mineral_ratio = 1.0

        vespene_ratio = self.vespene / 1500
        if vespene_ratio > 1.0:
            vespene_ratio = 1.0

        population_ratio = self.supply_left / self.supply_cap
        if population_ratio > 1.0:
            population_ratio = 1.0

        plausible_supply = self.supply_cap / 200.0

        military_weight = len(self.units(ROACH)) / (self.supply_cap-self.supply_left)
        if military_weight > 1.0:
            military_weight = 1.0

        cv2.line(game_data, (0, 19), (int(line_max*military_weight), 19), (250, 250, 200), 3)  # worker/supply ratio
        cv2.line(game_data, (0, 15), (int(line_max*plausible_supply), 15), (220, 200, 200), 3)  # plausible supply (supply/200.0)
        cv2.line(game_data, (0, 11), (int(line_max*population_ratio), 11), (150, 150, 150), 3)  # population ratio (supply_left/supply)
        cv2.line(game_data, (0, 7), (int(line_max*vespene_ratio), 7), (210, 200, 0), 3)  # gas / 1500
        cv2.line(game_data, (0, 3), (int(line_max*mineral_ratio), 3), (0, 255, 25), 3)

        self.flipped = cv2.flip(game_data, 0)

        if not HEADLESS:
            resized = cv2.resize(self.flipped, dsize=None, fx=2, fy=2)
            cv2.imshow('Intel', resized)
            cv2.waitKey(1)

    async def build_workers(self):
        if (len(self.units(HATCHERY)) * 16) > len(self.units(DRONE)) and len(self.units(DRONE)) < self.MAX_WORKERS:
            for larva in self.units(LARVA).ready.noqueue:
                if self.can_afford(DRONE):
                    await self.do(larva.train(DRONE))

    async def build_overlords(self):
        if self.supply_left < 10:
            for larva in self.units(LARVA).ready.noqueue:
                if self.can_afford(OVERLORD):
                    await self.do(larva.train(OVERLORD))

    async def build_extractor(self):
        for hatchery in self.units(HATCHERY).ready:
            vaspenes = self.state.vespene_geyser.closer_than(15.0, hatchery)
            for vaspene in vaspenes:
                if not self.can_afford(EXTRACTOR):
                    break
                worker = self.select_build_worker(vaspene.position)
                if worker is None:
                    break
                if not self.units(EXTRACTOR).closer_than(1.0, vaspene).exists:
                    await self.do(worker.build(EXTRACTOR, vaspene))

    async def expand(self):
        if self.units(HATCHERY).amount < (self.iteration / self.ITERATIONS_PER_MINUTE) and self.can_afford(HATCHERY):
            await self.expand_now()

    async def offensive_force_buildings(self):
        if self.units(HATCHERY).ready.exists:
            hatchery = self.units(HATCHERY).ready.random

            if self.units(HATCHERY).ready.exists and not self.units(SPAWNINGPOOL):
                if self.can_afford(SPAWNINGPOOL) and not self.already_pending(SPAWNINGPOOL):
                    await self.build(SPAWNINGPOOL, near=hatchery)

            elif len(self.units(HATCHERY)) < ((self.iteration / self.ITERATIONS_PER_MINUTE)/2):
                if self.can_afford(HATCHERY) and not self.already_pending(HATCHERY):
                    await self.build(HATCHERY, near=hatchery)

            if self.units(SPAWNINGPOOL).ready.exists and not self.units(ROACHWARREN):
                if self.can_afford(ROACHWARREN) and not self.already_pending(ROACHWARREN):
                    await self.build(ROACHWARREN, near=hatchery)

    async def build_offensive_force(self):
        for l in self.units(LARVA).ready.noqueue:
            #if not self.units(ZERGLING).amount > self.units(ROACH).amount:
                #if self.can_afford(ZERGLING) and self.supply_left > 0:
                    #await self.do(l.train(ZERGLING))

            if self.can_afford(ROACH) and self.supply_left > 0:
                await self.do(l.train(ROACH))

    def find_target(self, state):
        if len(self.known_enemy_units) > 0:
            return random.choice(self.known_enemy_units)
        elif len(self.known_enemy_structures) > 0:
            return random.choice(self.known_enemy_structures)
        else:
            return self.enemy_start_locations[0]
        
    async def attack(self):
        if len(self.units(ROACH).idle) > 0:
            choice = random.randrange(0, 4)
            target = False
            if self.iteration > self.do_something_after:
                if choice == 0:
                    # no attack
                    wait = random.randrange(20, 165)
                    self.do_something_after = self.iteration + wait

                elif choice == 1:
                    #attack_unit_closest_nexus
                    if len(self.known_enemy_units) > 0:
                        target = self.known_enemy_units.closest_to(random.choice(self.units(HATCHERY)))

                elif choice == 2:
                    #attack enemy structures
                    if len(self.known_enemy_structures) > 0:
                        target = random.choice(self.known_enemy_structures)

                elif choice == 3:
                    #attack_enemy_start
                    target = self.enemy_start_locations[0]

                if target:
                    for vr in self.units(ROACH).idle:
                        await self.do(vr.attack(target))
                y = np.zeros(4)
                y[choice] = 1
                print(y)
                self.train_data.append([y,self.flipped])

run_game(maps.get("(2)BurialGrounds"), [
    Bot(Race.Zerg, AloKostBot()),
    Computer(Race.Protoss, Difficulty.Easy)
], realtime=False)


I am not good at programming, but I tried to change both the destination and the direction to the folder, but nothing works.

The error is coming from numpy. Print out self.train_data and look at how it is structured. Numpy will not accept nested lists if they are all of different sizes. For example, you can make a numpy array from [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] but you cannot make an array from [[1,2,3],[4,5]] since the first row has 3 elements and the second has 2 (they most be consistent).

np.save writes a numpy array.  If the argument is not an array, it uses np.asarray(arg) first.  If your argument isn't array like at all, use pickle instead.  Or convert it array with dtype=object.  Your code is too long and involved to guess what train_data is like.
